# SQL queries and results

Tags: mysql, join, union, normalization

First off i want to apologize in case this is a known and answered question but English is not my native language and i don't know how to even search such a question. So here goes.

I have a table named movie. This table holds info about a movie. The director and the writer of the movie is also amongst the info i store. But both director and writer are multivalued attributes. As multivalued they should be stored in new tables but then those tables would have a many to many relationship withe the movie table, so i made four new tables.

Director -> directed -> MOVIE 
Writer -> wrote -> MOVIE

[Director] and [writer] hold names lastanames and an Id as key attribute. [directed], [wrote] hold the id key from director and writer tables AND the key from the movie table.

When i ask for the names of director(s) and writer(s) for a specific movie ( which has 3 directors and 2 writers ) the results i get are like ::

```
D.Name      D.Lastname      W.Name  W.Lastname
----------------------------------------------
Jan         Kounen          Stanley Kubric  
Albert      Hughes          Stanley Kubric  
Len         Wiseman         Stanley Kubric  
Jan         Kounen          Alan    Moore   
Albert      Hughes          Alan    Moore   
Len         Wiseman         Alan    Moore
```

If i use a union query i can get just the five names i want but not in a way i can understand who is the director and who is writer.

```
Jan     Kounen  
Albert  Hughes  
Len     Wiseman 
Stanley Kubric  
Alan    Moore
```

But are all listed as directors.

So my question is, is my design flawed? Is my query wrong? Is there a way to get directors and writers with one query without the multiple responses?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT::::

Thank you all for the replys.

I tried to upload an image for the relations but it wouldn't let me.
So here is the code for the tables in question

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`directed_by` (`Direc_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `Db_Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`Direc_id`, `Db_Title`) ,
INDEX `fk_Director_has_Movie_Movie1_idx` (`Db_Title` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Director_has_Movie_Director1_idx` (`Direc_id` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Director_has_Movie_Director1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Direc_id` )
REFERENCES `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`director` (`D_id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Director_has_Movie_Movie1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Db_Title` )
REFERENCES `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`movie` (`MV_Title` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`director` (`D_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`D_lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`D_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`D_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`movie` (`MV_Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`MV_Release_Date` DATE NOT NULL ,
`MV_Cost` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
`St_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`MV_Title`) ,
INDEX `fk_Movie_Studio1_idx` (`St_Name` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Movie_Studio1`
FOREIGN KEY (`St_Name` )
REFERENCES `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`studio` (`ST_Name` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`writen_by` (`Writ_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`Wb_Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`Writ_id`, `Wb_Title`) ,
INDEX `fk_Writer_has_movie_movie1_idx` (`Wb_Title` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_Writer_has_movie_Writer1_idx` (`Writ_id` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Writer_has_movie_Writer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Writ_id` )
REFERENCES `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`writer` (`W_id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Writer_has_movie_movie1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Wb_Title` )
REFERENCES `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`movie` (`MV_Title` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Red_Apple_storeDB`.`writer` (`W_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
`W_Lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`W_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`W_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

The one movie i ask for, has 3 directors and 2 writers.

my query ::

```
select d_name, d_lastname,d_id
from director, movie,directed_by
where mv_title = 'from hell'
and mv_title = db_title
and direc_id = d_id

union all

select w_name, w_lastname,w_id
from movie, writer, writen_by
where mv_title = 'from hell'
and mv_title = wb_title
and writ_id = w_id
```

Comment: with question like this, always provide sample records with desired result `:D` Welcome to StackOverFlow!

Comment: Specially showing the relationship between your movie, director tables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column in your select query that is simply named Writer or Producer.

```
SELECT .... , 'Writer' AS Type
UNION ALL
SELECT .... , 'Producer' AS Type
```

When you provide me the complete tablestructure I can give you the whole query if you like.

Comment: OOhhhh... Got it. thanks. Wouldnt cross my mind to do so. 

But i still wonder whether the design i end up with is good enough or not.